# Dot subscript summation notation used in design of experiments

Tags: experiment-design, terminology, notation, definition, sum

## Context

I couldn't find a clear explanation of this on this site, and
thought that it might be of use. I have provided part of the answer, which
anyone is welcome to build from. I'm not sure how to explain where this notation
is defined and where it isn't. I've provided an example at the end of this post,
but I'm not sure if it's suitable.

Once there's an answer to this post I will edit this so that the only section
here is "Question".

## Question

Often the notation $y_{..}$ is used, or $y_{i.}$, $y_{.j}$. I was wondering what
the definitions of this were and whether someone could give examples.

I'm also interested in where this notation doesn't apply, if I have an experiment where there are a few different varieties, each with a different number of experiments, does the notation work there?

## Definitions

$N = an$ is the total number of observations. Dot notation implies summation
over the subscript that it replaces.

$$
y_{i.} = \sum_{j = 1}^n y_{ij} \qquad \overline{y_{i.}} = y_{i.}/n
$$

$$
y_{..} = \sum_{j = 1}^a \sum_{j = 1}^n y_{ij} \qquad \overline{y_{..}} = y_{..}/N
$$

## Example

If we have

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|} 
\hline 3 & 4 & 6\\ \hline
7 & 2 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Then the following are some examples of the above definition

$$
\begin{align}
y_{..} &= 3 + 4 + 6 + 7 + 2 + 1 = 23 \\
\overline{y_{..}} &= (3 + 4 + 6 + 7 + 2 + 1)/6 = 23/6 \\
y_{1.} &= 3 + 4 + 6 = 13 \\
\overline{y_{1.}} &= (3 + 4 + 6)/3 = 13/3 \\
y_{.2} &= 4 + 2 = 6 \\
\overline{y_{.2}} &= (4 + 2) = 6/2
\end{align}
$$

## When doesn't dot notation apply

If we have instead

$$
\begin{array}{|l|c|c|} 
\hline  t_1 & 3 & 4 & 6\\ \hline
t_2 & 7 & 2 & 1 \\ \hline
t_3 & 1 & 9  \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Where this might represent experiements with three different types.

It seems that $y_{.3}$ isn't defined?

Comment: Dots are used as 'place holders' for subscripts that have 'disappeared' due to summing or averaging. Otherwise, it would be necessary to introduce alternative notation to distinguish between $\bar x_{.j}$ and $\bar x_{i.}.$ This dot-notation for sums is not used as often as the notation for averages. These notations need to be used with extra care in unbalanced designs.

Comment: There are different versions, so need to be defined clearly when used. Note the similarity to `R` notation `mymatrix[,1]` which is *all rows, first column* but without summation. With summation `sum(mymatrix[,1])`. Matlab has something similar.

Comment: right - it seems that having something that goes over this properly would be useful, which is why I made the post